# how to create a fully-expandable environment

Tags: environments, expansion, xparse

I know `DeclareDocumentCommand` from the package `xparse`. I am wondering if there is a version for environment ? 
I could also imagine a trick based on :

- declare the environment with `DeclareDocumentEnvironment`
- then redefine the "begin" part of the environment with `DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`

How safe is it ?

**EDIT1** The aim of this the following : i have a macro `\content` which i need to fully expand (in a `\edef`). Unfortunately, the replacement text of this macro contains several commands and environments. For example

```
\newcommand{\content}{blabla \textbf{text} blabla \othercommand[3]{text}    \begin{tabular} AA&BB\\CC&DD \end{tabular} blabla ...}
```

I just need to extract the arguments of each command and environment contained in `\content`. For this i redefine them, eg

```
\def\textbf#1{<bold>#1</bold>}
```

For the commands with optional parameters, I redefine them with `DeclareDocumentCommand`. But for environments, i don't knoy how to proceed.

Comment: Can't be done. An environment forms a group, and grouping (`\begingroup`/`\endgroup`) is not expandable. Also, tracking environment nesting requires an assignment.

Comment: What precisely do you want to achieve?

Comment: @egreg: please see my edit.

Comment: What should the contents of the `tabular` environment become? You can say `\def\begin#1{\csname #1\endcsname}` and `\def\tabular#1#2\end{tabular}{<tabular=#1>#2</tabular>}` but I guess it won't be sufficient. Writing a parser for *generic* tabular environments is not something I would endeavor.

Comment: @egreg: I don't understand the need of `\def\begin#1{\csname #1\endcsname}` ; I though `\begin{env}` does precisely `\env`. What did i miss ?

Comment: `\begin{env}` does *much* more than expanding `\env`: it's implicit in Joseph's comment. Look at the definition of `\begin` in `latex.ltx`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Other question : i don't think `\def\tabular#1#2\end{tabular}{<tabular=#1>#2</tabular>}` can work because you can't use `\end{tabular}` as delimiter since it contains `{}`, can you ?